# How to get a C# Custom TextBox to change cursor location on mouse click

Tags: c#, textbox, controls

I have a custom textbox, which is just a standard textbox with a couple additional small features, and it all works as expected.  The problem I am having is that clicking in the field to change the cursor location does not actually change the location of the cursor, the cursor just stays at the beginning of the field.

Below is the code I am working with, I am hoping someone will be able to tell me what I am missing:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test.UI.Controls
{
    public partial class TestTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private Color normalForegroundColor = Color.Gray;
        private Color textChangedForegroundColor = Color.Red;
        private string startingText = string.Empty;

        [Description("TextBox border color when text is changed"), Category("Appearance")]
        public Color TextChangedColor
        {
            get { return textChangedForegroundColor; }
            set { textChangedForegroundColor = value; }
        }

        [Description("Set starting text of textbox, as well as the Text property"), Category("Appearance")]
        public String StartingText
        {
            get { return startingText; }
            set 
            { 
                startingText = value;
                this.Text = startingText;
            }
        }

        public TestTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            normalForegroundColor = this.ForeColor;
        }

        protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
            this.ForeColor = this.Text == startingText ? normalForegroundColor : textChangedForegroundColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a screen grab of what the custom textbox looks like with data in it:
[image: Custom TextBox Example]

Comment: where exactly is the cursor code?

Comment: The code works for me. I just take away the TestReflectionTextBox method. Looks like you wanted as a constructor but it doesnt match the class name.

Comment: @Charlie I do not have any cursor code, I am inheriting TextBox. I would think that by doing that it would utilize the standard TextBox code for anything that I do not override?

Comment: @Diego I am sorry the constructor should have just been public TestTextBox(), I have made an edit to the code.  The code works fine for me bug if I type text into the field, and then click in the middle of a word, the cursor does not go to that location.  When you do that does it work for you?  Maybe this is just a workstation thing on my end, but the standard TextBox works fine?

Comment: @kenneth bray yes it works for me with the cursor behavior you describe... does you have something on the UI? You can just remove the partial statement on the class definition and inherit like you do from textbox. I think that way you can remove also the initializeComponent call.

Comment: @Diego I tried what you described, but it appears that it is required that it be a partial class, and removing the InitializeComponent call did not change anything either.  I updated the question to have a screenshot of the custom textbox I have in my UI.  No matter what I do the cursor stays to the left of the text, unless I use the arrow keys.. really odd